# HList mapping can't define type

Tags: scala, shapeless

With the following, I'm trying to get all the values of `Parameter` in an `HList`:

```
import shapeless._

case class Parameter[T](value: T)

trait ParameterOperations[Params <: HList, ParamValues <: HList] {
  def values(params: Params): ParamValues
}

object ParameterOperations {

  implicit val hNil = new ParameterOperations[HNil, HNil] {
    override def values(params: HNil) = HNil
  }

  implicit def hCons[HeadParam <: Parameter[HeadParamValue], TailParams <: HList, HeadParamValue, TailParamValues <: HList](
    implicit tailParamOperations: ParameterOperations[TailParams, TailParamValues]
  ) = new ParameterOperations[HeadParam :: TailParams, HeadParamValue :: TailParamValues] {

    override def values(params: HeadParam :: TailParams): HeadParamValue :: TailParamValues =
      params.head.value :: tailParamOperations.values(params.tail)
  }
}

object Test extends App {

  def getValues[Params <: HList, ParamValues <: HList](params: Params)(
    implicit parameterOperations: ParameterOperations[Params, ParamValues]
  ) = parameterOperations.values(params)

  val b = getValues(HList(Parameter(1), Parameter(true)))
  println(b)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] /Users/joangoyeau/Code/autowire/autowire/jvm/src/main/scala/Test.scala:30: could not find implicit value for parameter parameterOperations: ParameterOperations[shapeless.::[Parameter[Int],shapeless.::[Parameter[Boolean],shapeless.HNil]],ParamValues]
[error]   val b = getValues(HList(Parameter(1), Parameter(true)))
[error]                    ^
```

Isn't `ParamValues` supposed to be defined by the implicit `ParameterOperations`?

Answer (score 0):

Either specify type parameters explicitly

```
val b = getValues[Parameter[Int] :: Parameter[Boolean] :: HNil, Int :: Boolean :: HNil](HList(Parameter(1), Parameter(true)))
```

or exclude `HeadParam` from implicit `hCons` (`HeadParam` is not just `<: Parameter[HeadParamValue]`, actually it **is** `Parameter[HeadParamValue]`)

```
implicit def hCons[TailParams <: HList, HeadParamValue, TailParamValues <: HList](
  implicit tailParamOperations: ParameterOperations[TailParams, TailParamValues]
) = new ParameterOperations[Parameter[HeadParamValue] :: TailParams, HeadParamValue :: TailParamValues] {

  override def values(params: Parameter[HeadParamValue] :: TailParams): HeadParamValue :: TailParamValues =
      params.head.value :: tailParamOperations.values(params.tail)
}
```

---

By the way, instead of your custom type class `ParameterOperations` you can use standard `shapeless.ops.hlist.Comapped` and `shapeless.ops.hlist.NatTRel`

```
object paramToIdNatTransform extends (Parameter ~> Id) {
  override def apply[T](param: Parameter[T]): T = param.value
}

def getValues[Params <: HList, ParamValues <: HList](params: Params)(implicit
  comapped: Comapped.Aux[Params, Parameter, ParamValues],
  natTRel: NatTRel[Params, Parameter, ParamValues, Id]
): ParamValues = natTRel.map(paramToIdNatTransform, params)

val b = getValues(HList(Parameter(1), Parameter(true)))
println(b) // 1 :: true :: HNil
```

---

Actually it's even simpler, `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper` is enough, so you can write

```
val b = HList(Parameter(1), Parameter(true)).map(paramToIdNatTransform)
println(b) // 1 :: true :: HNil
```